# Spring and thread: No Session found for current thread

Tags: multithreading, spring, hibernate

in a webapp i want to run an async thread for a long process and let the client knows the progress status.
For this i thought to use this abstract class:

```
public abstract class ThreadProvider implements Runnable{

    protected Thread thread;

    public boolean create() throws SystemException{
        if(thread!=null && thread.isAlive()) throw new SystemException("Il processo è già in esecuzione");
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        return true;
    }
}
```

And this is my impl:

```
@Service @Transactional
public class ChiusuraProvider extends ThreadProvider {

    private static Logger gdf = Logger.getLogger("gdf");
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ChiusuraProvider.class);

    protected Dao dao;
    protected CinetelProvider cinetelProvider;

    @Override
    public void run() {...}
}
```

Everything works: the thread starts and seems that the autowire works... however Hibernat did not find any session (maybe because i change thread)... how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Transactional` doesn't work in this case, see [10.5.1 Understanding the Spring Framework's declarative transaction implementation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained).

You can use programmatic transaction management (`TransactionTemplate`) inside your `run` method, or extract transactional logic into separate bean and make it `@Transactional`.